# Animating a div tag and after cearten time hide that using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to animate a div tag left 300px and after 3 seconds it will be hide and I want to do this whole process at every 8 seconds. In my code it does only one time. It doesn't repeat the whole precess. Following is the my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
var div=$("div");
div.animate({left:'300px'},"slow");
setTimeout(function(){
div.animate({opacity:'0'},"slow"); }, 3000);

},8000);
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>

    <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    (function moveit(){
        $("div")
            .css({opacity:'1',left:0})// reset (assuming you want it back visible and on the left)
            .animate({left:'300px'},"slow")// move right
            .delay(3000)// wait 3 seconds
            .animate({opacity:'0'},"slow");// fade out
        setTimeout(moveit, 8000);//do this again after 8 seconds
    })(); // self-execute.

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99phku9d/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `repeat` functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").repeat(8000).animate({left:'300px'},"slow").setTimeout(function(){
   div.animate({opacity:'0'},"slow"); }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (http://jsfiddle.net/8fmwkvyt/1/)